# Command to find text from one document copy it and paste it to another

Tags: sed, copy-paste

I'm thinking of using `sed`.  I have:

```
sed -i -e '/Robert/w  file2.txt' -e '//d' file1.txt
```

If possible, I'm looking to copy (not cut) anything from `file1.txt` that has the word `Robert` in that line and then the whole line above it into a brand new document.

Also it needs to add to the second file at the very start some text which needs to be entered when running the command.

Comment: Something like `grep -B1 'Robert' file1 >newfile2` ??

Comment: thats great does what i want thankyou how would i add on the first line of the new file some text from the same command

Comment: Something like `{ echo "this is first line" && grep -B1 'Robert' file1; } >newfile2` ??

Comment: yes this is nearly there but when its finding 'Robert' its adding the line -B1 to the "this is first line" on line one

Comment: basically start the line before Robert from line2 in the new file

Comment: Give sample input and expected output

Comment: nevermind it was me, it was adding it to the next line,the command works, if i manually run this command it works, but i cant seem to auto script it am i missing something

Comment: Is that something to edit into your question or have you given up on that question? In the latter case let us know that we should vote for closing the question as not reproduceable problem.